# About possible chain reactions of free() in C' stdlib.h

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct strt;
typedef struct {
    int i;
    struct strt *next;
} strt;

strt *s1 = malloc(sizeof(strt));
strt *s2=s1->next = malloc(sizeof(strt));

free(s1);
```

Now, does `free(s1)` deallocate the block pointed to by s1 only or those pointed to by s1 **and** s1->next/s2?

I understand this must be a question asked a thousand times, but I 
couldn't manage to describe this the the search engine, neither could
I find direct mention of the same issue in documentation of the `free()` function.

Comment: How on Earth would `free()` know about the internal structure of your struct? All it knows is that it's a `void *`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `free` per `malloc`. So you have to free `s1` and `s2` separately. Either:

```
free(s1);
free(s2);
```

Or:

```
free(s1->next);
free(s1);
```

In the second case, the statements's order is important, because you can't acceed to the objet referenced by `s1` if `s1` is freed.

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.22.3.3 The `free` function**
>   The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.

Comment: +1, perfect answer citing the Standard and explaining it also using logic.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have a memory leak. Only the memory pointed to by `s1` is freed, not the one pointed to by `s2` and `s1->next`. So you need

```
free(s1);
free(s2);
```

A good rule of thumb is to have a `free` for every `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The `free` function has no idea of the structure behind the block of memory being released. A call to `free` releases only the block pointed to by the pointer passed as its argument. In your case, you need to release `s1->next` first, and then the `s1` itself:

```
free(s1->next);
free(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak i.e. you have lost the pointer to some memory previously allocated by `malloc` and no longer have that pointer to pass to `free`.

You should call `free` in reverse order to the `mallocs` from structures of this nature.